# root of a unit in a real biquadratic field

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ two  primes numbers $\equiv 1\pmod 4$. If we note by $\varepsilon_m$ the fundamental unit of real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$,  then how can be solved in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{p_1p_2})$ the following equation:
\begin{equation*}
    \varepsilon_{2}\varepsilon_{p_1p_2}\varepsilon_{2p_1p_2}=X^2
\end{equation*}

Comment: Posted here as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123791/root-of-a-unit-in-a-real-biquadratic-field

Answer (score 5):

The classical literature on the computation of the unit groups of multiquadratic number fields
are

- S. Kuroda,  *Über den Dirichletschen Körper*,
  J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo, Sect. I 4 (1943), 383-406 
  (arithmetic proof of the class number formula)
- S. Kuroda, Über die Klassenzahlen algebraischer Zahlkörper,
  Nagoya Math. J. 1 (1950), 1-10
- H. Wada, 
   *On the class number and the unit group of certain algebraic number fields*,
  J. Fac. Sci., Univ. Tokyo, Sect. I 13 (1966), 201-209

The last reference in particular will contain an algorithm for solving your equation.